# SSIS Connection to MySQL when run in Jobagent

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis, sql-agent-job

I need to use SSIS to copy data from a external MySQL database to another external SQL database. When I run the pacakge in Visual stidio, everything works fine. But when I deploy 
to a local Integration services catalog (on local SQL server) and run the package through jobagent, I get the following error:

> The AcquireConnection method call to the connectionmanager MySQLDB.com 
>   failed with error code 0xC0014009.

The validation of the ODBC connection to (MySQL) is failing. I am using MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver. But as stated above, it works when running the same package in Visual studio...

I have plenty of packages running and working in jobagent but none is using a connection other then to SQL server.

What am I missing here with the MySQL Connection?

Comment: Usually it's permissions.   In visual studio, the package runs as you, with your permissions.   In the job, it runs as the SQL Agent, with the SQL Agent's permissions.

Comment: What Tab is suggesting sounds right to me... **You** have the ODBC drivers available to you. The account running as SQL Agent probably doesn't! To test this; change the SQL Agent _service_ to run under your credentials and see if it makes a difference!